# What causes colour discrepancies on borders after scrolling?

Tags: wpf, colors, scroll

We noticed some weird behaviour in our WPF application.

We have a customised, expander like UserControl, which has a Border around it - we'll call it expander. There can be several of these expanders in a view, which means scrolling is needed. When an expander is scrolled out of view, and back again, the border sometimes changes colour. Not every time, and not consistantly. For example, the lower border can be slighly lighter in colour, while the right border can be darker, even though they use the same brush. The next time it's scrolled out of view, and back again, the colours can be back to normal.

It almost looks like a scaling/antialiasing effect. Has anyone else seen this behaviour, and is there anything we can do about it?

To complicate things a bit - but only a bit - the expanders are children of a ListView. This is because we want to emulate HTML anchoring, so we externally can jump directly to a given expander. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: May be `VirtualizedStackPanel` is your problem? without xaml its hard to say the reason of such behavior.

Comment: It's a combination of XAML and ViewModel code that add and draw the controls, which would be be very hard to condense to a purposive post. I'm taking a chance, hoping someone might've seen something similar - or know of a known bug causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a anti-aliasing issue, as explained [here](http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/09/21/391-anti-aliasing-can-lead-to-fuzzy-gui-elements/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).